# General syntax question when dropping a column within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
season_stats.drop(season_stats [season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG'].index, inplace = True)
```

when dropping a specific value within a column in python, Why is `season_stats` written twice inside the parenthesis? Why isn't it enough for

`season_stats.drop(season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG'].index, inplace = True)` to work?

This is just a general syntax question data doesn't need to be provided.

Comment: Try:  `season_stats.drop((season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG').index, inplace = True)`

Comment: For dropping a particular value, it's easier to do: `df = df[df['Pos'].ne('SF-SG')]`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the outputs of your various pieces.

---

```
season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG'
```

Returns a Series of True/False values, but `pd.DataFrame.drop` requires either indices or columns to be specified.

---

```
(season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG').index
```

Returns all of your indices, it can't magically know that you only want `True` values.

---

Therefore, we tell it we only want True values, and then take the index of this *filtered* DataFrame:

```
season_stats[season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG'].index
```

---

If you want to be fancy, we can filter using a `lambda` like so:

```
(season_stats['Pos'] == 'SF-SG')[lambda x: x].index
```